# extract substrings of text between two repeating strings

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a dataframe created using readtext(). It has two columns: doc_id, text. For each row (doc_id) I want to extract a substring (in my case name of a government department) between two strings that are repeated n times in the text column. For example:

```
documents <- data.frame(doc_id = c("doc_1", "doc_2"),
                        text = c("PART 1 Department of Communications \n Matters \n Blah blah blah \n PART 2 Department of Forestry \n Matters \n Blah blah blah", "PART 1 Department of Communications \n Matters \n Blah blah blah \n PART 3 Department of Health \n Matters \n Blah blah blah \n PART 5 Department of Sport \n Matters \n Blah blah"))
```

What I would like is to get to is:

```
"doc_1"  "Department of Communications, Department of Forestry"
"doc_2"  "Department of Communications, Department of Health, Department of Sport"
```

Essentially I want to extract string between PART and Matters. I would like to use dplyr::rowwise operations on the dataframe but have no idea how to extract multiple times between two repeated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not think of a `rowwise` solution right now, but maybe this helps as well

```
library(dplyr)
documents %>%
  mutate(text=strsplit(as.character(text), 'PART ')) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(text) %>%
  mutate(text=trimws(sub('\\d+ (.*) Matters.*', '\\1', text))) %>%
  filter(text != '') %>%
  group_by(doc_id) %>%
  summarise(text=paste(text, collapse=', '))
```

It basically splits all your text at `PART` and then we can work on each element separate to cut the important text out of the longer string. Later we concatenate everything together per `doc_id`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_match_all` from `stringr` and extract the words in between "PART" and "Matters". It returns a list of two column matrices from which we select the second column which is the capture group and put them in one comma separated string using `toString`.

```
out <- stringr::str_match_all(documents$text, "PART \\d+ (.*) \n Matters")
sapply(out, function(x) toString(x[, 2]))

#[1] "Department of Communications, Department of Forestry"                   
#[2] "Department of Communications, Department of Health, Department of Sport"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import Tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

#Use helper variable name to store resuts of the extracted departments based on the parttern
Helper <- str_extract_all(string = documents$text, pattern = "Department.*\\n")

#Clean Up the columns.
Helper1 <- lapply(Helper, FUN = str_replace_all, pattern=" \\n", replacement = ", ")
documents$Departments<-str_replace(str_trim(unlist(lapply(Helper1, FUN =paste, collapse= ""))), pattern = ",$", replacement = "")

#Remove Previous column of texts
documents <- select(documents, -c("text"))
```

This yields
[image]